# Multi sock5 with gecko browser?

Tags: c#, multithreading, gecko

my code in mainform get url, ip_sock, port_sock from file, then call to form gecko to navigate to url with ip_sock and porrt_sock

```
 for (int L = 0; L < links.Length; L++ )
        {
            _link = links[L].Split('|');
            url = _link[0];
            referal = _link[1];


            for (int j = 0; j < _threads; j++)
            {
                _px = Pxs[j].Split(':');
                _ip = _px[0];
                _port = Int32.Parse(_px[1]);

                // random User-agent from list
                var rand_UA = new Random();
                int randomUA = rand_UA.Next(0, Uas.Length - 1);
                string UA = Uas[randomUA];
                // random view time 
               // var rand_time = new Random();
                //times = rand_time.Next(20, 30);
                //
                #region create new browser
                Browser_app br = new Browser_app(url, referal, UA, _ip, _port);
                br.Show();

                #endregion
            }
        }
```

in form gecko i have a code:

```
public Browser_app(string Links, string Referal, string ua, string Ip, int Port)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        #region navigate to url with custom data                       
        Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize("xulrunner");
        Gecko.GeckoPreferences.Default["extensions.blocklist.enabled"] = false;
        Gecko.GeckoPreferences.Default["general.useragent.override"] = ua;
        Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.type"] = 1;
        Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.socks"] = Ip;
        Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.socks_port"] = Port;
        Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.socks_version"] = 5;
        geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate(Links);                                           
        #endregion                       
    }
```

and my problems:https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pLrj.png

**I want them to be different in 2 browser 
Please help me ! thanks !**

Comment: any progress on this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is no problem with type of proxies.
Gecko doesn't support multithreading calling from same UI.
You would need to create a separate project and call via cmd geckoBrowser.
Like this, only you can accomplish "multithreading"
Hope it helps.

Comment: can you plz add an example on how we can do that